# Error in value [[3L]] (cond): disable multibyte string at when publishing on shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm new to R and shiny and this is my first post. When I try to follow the link shinyapps.io issues the following:

```
Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

serverInfo

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : invalid multibyte string at '<c7><c0> <ce> 
<d1><cd><ce><c2><d3><2d><cf><ee><f7><e0><f2><ee><ea><20><f1><e5><f1>�<bf>'
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Ukrainian words "ЗА", "УТРИМАВСЯ", "НЕ ГОЛОСУВАВ" must be mandatory.
Now in RStudio "default text encoding - UTF-8". Tried to change to System default, windows-1252 - does not help.
Point in which direction to dig.

Here is my program:

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
library(rsconnect)

pa_csv1<-getwd()
pa_csv<-paste0(pa_csv1,"/Fin_Gol1.csv")
aa1 <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=17s1RUvj- 
7AY5Zw3o-_21sbO87fPz1ZvE", encoding = "ukr")
aa2<-as.data.frame(aa1)
aa2<-as.data.table(aa2)
aa<-aa2
bb<-subset(aa, select = c(NameProject, Deputat, As_Voted, Party, Za, NV, 
Ag ))
cols<-c("NameProject", "Deputat", "As_Voted", "Party", "Za", "NV", "Utr")
colnames(bb)<-cols
bb<-as.data.table(bb)
bb1<-bb
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("WINDOW"),
fluidRow(
 column(3,
        selectInput("var1",
                   "Deputat:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(aa$Deputat))))
 ),
column(3,
       selectInput("Gol",
                   "Golosyvannya:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(aa$As_Voted))))
 ),
 column(3,
        selectInput("Proj",
                   "Name_Project",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(aa$NameProject))))
 ),
 column(3,
       selectInput("Party",
                   "Партія:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(aa$Party))))
),

mainPanel(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      4,
      dataTableOutput ("selected_var2")

    ),
    column(
      8,
      dataTableOutput ("selected_var1")
      #img(src="Bych.png")

    )
  )

 )

)

 )
 server <- function(input, output)
 {

 output$selected_var1<-renderDataTable ({
  data1<-bb1
 if(input$var1 !="All"){
   data1<-data1[data1$Deputat == input$var1,]
 }

 if (input$Gol !="All"){
   data1 <-data1[data1$As_Voted ==input$Gol,]
 }
 if (input$Proj !="All"){
   data1 <-data1[data1$NameProject==input$Proj,]
 }
 if (input$Party !="All"){
   data1 <-data1[data1$Party==input$Party,]
 }
 data1
 })


#--------------Second var---------------------
output$selected_var2<-renderDataTable ({
data1<-bb1
o1<-nrow(filter(bb1, bb1$As_Voted=="ЗА"))
o2<-nrow(filter(bb1, bb1$As_Voted=="НЕ ГОЛОСУВАВ"))
o3<-nrow(filter(bb1, bb1$As_Voted=="УТРИМАВСЯ"))
o<-data.table(Za=o1, Protu=o2, Utrum = o3)
if(input$var1 !="All"){
  #ff1<-nrow(filter(aa, aa$Deputat == input$var1))
  data1<-data1[data1$Deputat == input$var1 & data1$As_Voted =="ЗА",]
  o1<-nrow(data1)
}

if (input$var1 !="All"){
  data1<-bb1[bb1$Deputat == input$var1 & bb1$As_Voted =="НЕ ГОЛОСУВАВ",]
  o2<-nrow(data1)
}
if (input$var1 !="All"){
  data1<-bb1[bb1$Deputat == input$var1 & bb1$As_Voted =="УТРИМАВСЯ",]
  o3<-nrow(data1)
}
# if (input$Party !="All"){
#   data1 <-data1[data1$Party==input$Party,]
#   o<-nrow(filter(bb1, bb1$As_Voted=="ЗА"))
# }
o<-data.table(Za=o1, Protu=o2, Utrum = o3)
o


#paste(ff1, spisok$NameProject,"   ", spisok$Deputat)
#ff2<-(ff1$NameProject)
#ff<-data.frame(ff2)
#View(ff1)
#paste0("  ", ff1, "+", spisok$NameProject)
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a link to the data file:
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=17s1RUvj-7AY5Zw3o-_21sbO87fPz1ZvE]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the coding. I solved the problem as follows. I wrote my data to txt-file with parameter fileEncoding = "UTF-8" (in output function) and read this file with parameter encoding = "UTF-8" (in input function). And my App was deployed. You can read more detail  https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html. But in your cases maybe the solving will be another...